# This is regarding antd paginations. Is it possible to customize the text shown in the square box/ dropdown that shows the page count/pages

Tags: reactjs, antd

As written above, is it possible to custmomize what's shown there?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use `pageSizeOptions` props to customize the options. By default it starts with 10. So use `pageSize="{min_size}"` to start the options from number you want and add other size options in the array like `pageSizeOptions={["20","25"]}`.

```
<Pagination defaultCurrent={1} 
total={50} showSizeChanger 
pageSizeOptions={["20","25"]} 
pageSize="20"/>
```

[image]